# Library for Python: How to call C++ functions from Python program?

Tags: c++, python, dll, shared-libraries

There is a library for Python that enables the calling ability (can call functions in C++ format without *extern "C"*. Please, could you remind me the name of the library? I forgot it's name and can't find it.

It's not Boost.Python.

Thank you very much. Your answer will be rewarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are thinking of [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Are you thinking of [Boost](http://www.boost.org/).[Python](http://www.boost.org/libs/python/)?

Comment: @s.zakharov: I am trying to do the same, any possible step by step tutorials to do so? I have just started using Python yesterday and am quite confused about accessing c++ functions via Python. I believe this page does have a good amount of information, but since you are already on the same topic, could you provide me with any links for a step by step tutorial? Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Also, ctypes lets you access dlls and wrap c code
[ctypes doc](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes)

Answer (score 1):

SWIG, Boost.Python, SIP, Shiboken, PyBindgen, ...

SWIG and Boost.Python are most popular, i.e. they have the largest user base and the most active development teams. Which of these two to use is largely a matter of taste. So if you don't want to use Boost.Python, then SWIG is the obvious choice.